# Concurrent reading in oracle?

Tags: oracle

Say we have customer table which has record

```
CustId    LastName
1          Hamlin
```

In one request we get the customer last name as Hamlin for custId=1. We update the last name to Kathy but do not commit it.

Another request comes it also try to get the last name for custId=1. Will it get Kathy or Hamlin.

My understanding is that if both the request get different connection object(which should be the case) the second request will get to see the Hamlin. But if they get same connection object , then second request object will see the last name as Kathy. P

lease let me know if above understanding is correct?

Comment: Wait, is your connection pool handing out connections with uncommitted an transaction‽ This first thing the connection pool should do upon being returned a connection is rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're in read-committed transaction isolation level (or higher, Oracle supports no lower), you will not see changes made by uncommitted *other* transactions, ever. Beware that especially in serializable mode, your query may be required to wait for other transaction to commit or rollback, or alternatively your transaction may be rolled back for you.

Oracle only supports read committed and serializable (you can pick, e.g., via `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`); other database systems additional support read-uncommitted, which would allow you to see the updated but not yet committed value.

Answer (score 1):

if you are in the same transaction, you will see your uncommitted values (but not other peoples/transactions).

any other access will see the most recently read-consistent view of the things that have been comitted.

Comment: Hi i have a question on if you are in the same transaction, you will see your uncommitted values (but not other peoples/transactions). Say we are using JDBC. can we say same transaction means same connection? Not sure we can refer the "same transaction" term in jdbc as we simply create the connection, statement and then excecute the query.

Comment: if there is an implicit COMMIT in between calls, then no, you are not in the same transaction.